# How to find difference between two column [col1-col2]

Tags: dataframe, go, gota

I am using Go [gota/dataframe](https://github.com/go-gota/gota).

I want to subtract value of 2 columns and store it into a new column.

I searched a lot but no luck, please help.

```
   df := dataframe.ReadCSV(csvfile, dataframe.WithDelimiter(';'))
   fmt.println(df)
```

Output:

```
   accountId deposit Withdrawals
    anil0001  50      10
    vikas0002 10      10
    ravi0003  20      10
    user1111  NaN     20
```

I want diff of deposit and Withdrawals in new column

```
  accountId deposit Withdrawals deposit_Withdrawals_diff
   anil0001  50      10         40
   vikas0002 10      10         0
   ravi0003  20      10.        10
   user1111  0       20.        -20
```

Comment: Please provide code examples of what you are trying to do, the more you can do to help other developers understand the specifics of your problems, the easier it will be to help you.

Comment: added more details please check

Answer (score 1):

Gota/dataframe look's interesting. So I had a look.
I have a somehow working solution for your question but it does not feel good. Maybe someone will find a cleaner solution.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"

    "github.com/go-gota/gota/dataframe"
    "github.com/go-gota/gota/series"
)

func main() {
    csvStr := `accountId,deposit,Withdrawals
anil0001,50,10
vikas0002,10,10
ravi0003,20,10
user1111,NaN,20`

    df := dataframe.ReadCSV(strings.NewReader(csvStr))

    // Within a row, elements are indexed by their column index.
    indexDeposit := 1
    indexWithdrawals := 2

    // Rapply reads the data by rows. 
    // You can access each element of the row using 
    // s.Elem(index) or s.Val(index).
    // To browse by columns use Capply.
    s := df.Rapply(func(s series.Series) series.Series {
        deposit, err := s.Elem(indexDeposit).Int()
        if err != nil {
            return series.Ints("NAN")
        }
        withdrawal, err := s.Elem(indexWithdrawals).Int()
        if err != nil {
            return series.Ints("NAN")
        }
        return series.Ints(deposit - withdrawal)
    })

    // The new series is appended to 
    // the data source via a call to Mutate. 
    // You can print s to read its content.
    df = df.Mutate(s.Col("X0")).
        Rename("deposit_Withdrawals_diff", "X0")

    fmt.Println(df)
}
```

Outputs:

```
$ go run .
[4x4] DataFrame

    accountId deposit Withdrawals deposit_Withdrawals_diff
 0: anil0001  50      10          40
 1: vikas0002 10      10          0
 2: ravi0003  20      10          10
 3: user1111  NaN     20          NaN
    <string>  <int>   <int>       <int>
```

https://play.golang.org/p/FPIxep_CW9P

Comment: `Cbind` can be used as such `fmt.Println(df.CBind(s.Rename("deposit_Withdrawals_diff", "X0")))` like in https://play.golang.org/p/L38ajnhWM0k

Comment: but i have not tried to figure out which is fastest. I have only noticed that mutates performed a copy, and a lot of iterations.